# How to call MongoDB from Browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I want to call the MongoDB directly from Browser JavaScript. Without wasting my time writing Server API with Express.JS.

Is there libraries that can do that?

**How it may work:**

It's trivial to execute query from the Browser, but the problem is the security. I see one possible way how it could be made safe. You write the Browser JavaScript and mark such server calls with special tags like in code below:

```
...

// SERVER_QUERY_START
async function getPosts(query_params) {
  return db.collection("posts")
    .find({ user_id: query_params.user_id })
    .toArray()
}
// SERVER_QUERY_END

...
```

Then during the Client Build process Client JavaScript source code is scanned for such queries and they are extracted and stored somewhere on the server, as **allowed queries**.

Then when the **Browser sends the query function as string** to Server for execution, the server validates if this query function is in the list of allowed queries, and if so it executes it. Also, when the Server executes query, it overrides some parameters in the `query_params` like `user_id`.

Are there libraries that would do that? (I know about Meteor.JS, but it's doing something different, too complicated. GraphQL also too complicated and bloated. I want simple way I can use with React.JS and Svelte).

Comment: You cant use database in client side but you can call them with ajax or socketio fron server.

Comment: @bahoz99 the database call itself is trivial, you just eval JS send from the Browser, the problem is how to make it safe.

Comment: Create a rest api and for getting db value. And use session authentication.

Comment: apart from the fact that what you're proposing will require code which runs on a server, the suggested implementation is no less complex than a typical API server which uses a mongodb database adapter.  just use node.js+express or whatever other backend tooling you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an intermediate service since there are no common protocols between browsers and MongoDB (browsers speak FTP/HTTP and MongoDB uses its own binary protocol).

https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch/faq is a MongoDB-provided intermediate service that should fit the bill.